# data from printf getting written into file when used with write() as argument

Tags: c, system-calls

I wrote this piece to write some data in some file:

```
//CODE 1
int retval=open("hello.txt",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|S_IRUSR);
int len=6;

if(retval<0)
{
    printf("wrong\n");
}
else
    printf("abcd %ld",write(retval,"hello",len));
```

Now I noticed that the `abcd` from the `printf` is also getting written in the file if I increase the value of `len` (say `len=9`):

```
//CODE 2 with value of len=9
int retval;

while((retval=getchar())!=EOF)
{
    if(retval!='\0')
        printf("%c",retval);
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nfound null-termination\n\n");
    }
}
```

the output for 2nd code is:

```
//value of len is 9 in this case
hello

found null-termination

abc
```

Now I can't understand how `abcd` from `printf` is also getting inserted into the file - is it because the data in `printf` is not waiting for the data in the out-stream to be flushed into the file (inserted by `write()` first), hence both are getting written in the file?

Comment: I am sure I have seen this before

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, I delete this after posting it 3-4 days ago - as there was no response & I was afraid that this might get buried down under the new questions being asked on the forum.

Comment: Does this latest version with 6 instead of 10 works?

Comment: @EdHeal Yes it does - it will print entire `abcd` from `printf` apart from `hello` and `\0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is ***undefined behaviour***! Specifically, in the call to `write`, you are giving, as the 2nd argument , a string literal of length `5` but telling it, in the 3rd argument, there are **9** bytes.

In your case, I presume the compiler is placing the `abcd %ld` data (also a string-literal) in memory immediately after the `hello` data, so that's why it's writing `abcd`.

But this should not be relied upon, by the way! It's entirely up to the compiler how it arranges such string-literal data in memory. And it's entirely up to the programmer to ensure that the "size" argument to `write` is valid - your value of `9` is ***not*** valid, hence, **undefined behaviour**.

PS: The call to `write` will be executed **before** the `printf` function is called - this is *not* undefined.

Comment: @EdHeal OP's question: *Now I noticed that the abcd from the printf is also getting written in the file if I increase the value of len (say len=9):*

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, I know there should be a null-terminator. Don't really know how/why that's being skipped: that's the nature of UB, I guess?

Comment: You tell it to write 9 bytes. Does not care about the values of those bytes. So does its best. Hence undefined behaviour. Depends on how the compiler works where the 4 bytes come from. Or if they exist